# Closed form expression for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^k \alpha^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

How do I determine if this series converge: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^k \alpha^i = 1 + (\alpha + 1) + (\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1) + \dotsc$$

where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

If it converges, does there exist a closed-form expression of the series?

Comment: what do you you know about $\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha^i $ ?

Comment: Hint (I haven't thought through). Each of the summands is a finite geometric progression, so $(a^n -1)/(a-1)$.

Comment: It diverges badly, $\alpha^{k+1}-1$ is the term of a divergent series.

Comment: If $\alpha=1,$ it should be completely clear that the series diverges. Otherwise, $$\sum_{i=0}^k\alpha^i=\frac{\alpha^{k-1}-1}{\alpha-1},$$ and the series can be shown to diverge (for different reasons) when $|\alpha|<1,$ when $\alpha=-1,$ and when $|\alpha|>1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, recall that (*necessary condition*)

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \;\text{converges} \implies a_k \to 0$$

but in this case, for $|\alpha|\neq 1$

$$a_k=\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha^i \to\frac1{\alpha-1}$$

and for the cases $\alpha= \pm 1$ also $a_k\not \to 0$.